# WPF MSI WIX INSTALLATION: How to add a choice of 2 projects instead of one

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I inherited this project from a client, and I am new to WPF, but got their existing project modified and added a new project to an existing project-One. I also created a virtual server Hyper-V machine to test the MSI package, which installs and works.

**1. PROBLEM**

But now I want an option to choose between Project-One and Project-Two. As currently it is only built for the former ie Project-One.

**2. WHAT I HAVE DONE**
I changed the feature.wxs file from

```
 <Feature Id="ProjectOneModuleFeature" />
```

to

```
<Feature Id="ProjectOneModuleFeature" Title="Test Integration" Description="blah blah" Absent="allow" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="expand" Level="1"> <ComponentRef Id="ProjectOneModuleFeature"/> <ComponentRef Id="ProjectTwoModuleFeature"/> </Feature>
```

I also duplicated the ProjectOne.wxs to created the 2nd and renamed the Id's to match the feature file. However when I try to build it, it crashes.

As I said I am new to this and not sure which is the best approach.

Please help
Ed

Comment: Your question contains two sections with heading "2. WHAT I HAVE DONE", which are almost, but not completely identical. Please [edit] your question to remove the section that is not the correct one.

Comment: hi @KlausGütter sorry about the mix up, its been updated now. thanks

Comment: "when I try to build it, it crashes"- do you build using the CLI tools (candle etc) or within Visual Studio? How exactly does it crash (error message?)